# Persistence of a large number of objects

Tags: python, persistence

I have some code that I am working on that scrapes some data from a website, and then extracts certain key information from that website and stores it in an object.  I create a couple hundred of these objects each day, each from unique url's.  This is working quite well, however, I'm inexperienced in what options are available to me in Python for persistence and what would be best suited for my needs.

Currently I am using pickle.  To do so, I am keeping all of these webpage objects and appending them in a list as new ones are created, then saving that list to a pickle (then reloading it whenever the list is to be updated).  However, as i'm in the order of some GB of data, i'm finding pickle to be somewhat slow.  It's not unworkable, but I'm wondering if there is a more well suited alternative.  I don't really want to break apart the structure of my objects and store it in a sql type database, as its important for me to keep the methods and the data as a single object.

Shelve is one option I've been looking into, as my impression is then that I wouldn't have to unpickle and pickle all the old entries (just the most recent day that needs to be updated), but am unsure if this is how shelve works, and how fast it is.

So to avoid rambling on, my question is: what is the preferred persistence method for storing a large number of objects (all of the same type), to keep read/write speed up as the collection grows?

Comment: Take a look at the [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed ZODB, but I now realize my question might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's suggestion could be one of the alternatives.

You may consider to store the pickle objects directly in a sqlite database which still can manage from the python standard library.

Use a StringIO object to convert between the database column and python object.

You didn't mention the size of each object you are pickling now. I guess it should stay well within sqlite's limit.

Comment: Thanks Toruk.  I checked using sys.getsizeof() on my objects and they are about 72bytes each.  Do you know if ZODB or sqlite would be faster?

Comment: The ZODB would be *simpler* and transparent.

Comment: @Martijn, i cannot agree more. it is just if i haven't yet figure out what to do with all the pickle objects on hand and i want to address the performance issue. sqlite comes with the standard library so i thought probably can save some time to read through the document, tweak around the package installation and proof-of-concept. and there are other object database then zodb. probably need to have some evaluation before one can jump onboard with any one of those object dbs.